# i can't add Arabic numbers thru java to oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, multilingual

I'm facing a problem with adding Arabic number to oracle 10g database. Arabic words are added successfully but if i add number in my string then numbers are saved as ?? in the database.

I thing i should fix the java code so it can add number cause if i change ?? with Arabic number in oracle SQL developer it's work fine.
Here is a example : 'قبل اكثر من  ?? شهر' --> this should be like this 'قبل اكثر من  ١٢ شهر'

i have change the database character set and NLS_LANG so oracle could support Arabic.

Please i need help.

Comment: What is the table collation?  Also, I think Arabic numerals, strictly speaking, are the numbers we use, e.g. `1, 2, 3...`

Comment: first , how can i change the table collation in oracle 10g. Yes, arabic numerals are 1, 2 exmple : ١,٢. thank you for your help.

Comment: but i'm confused, why i can add arabic number successfully thru oracle sql developer software but when i add these numbers from java it doesn't work.

Comment: Show us your Java code.  This sounds like an encoding problem, specifically your data on the Java side is being improperly encoded before it goes over to Oracle.

Comment: "why i can add arabic number successfully thru oracle sql developer software but not in java", because these are not the same langages ? One is SQL and the other is Java.

Comment: oh really , thank you for this info.

Answer (score 0):

this is servlet part.

```
String PeriodNameList=request.getParameter("PeriodNameList");
DataBaseConnection DataBaseConnection=new DataBaseConnection();
Con = DataBaseConnection.getConnection();
AgendaPeriodesBean AgendaPeriodesBean=null;
String [] SplitedPeriodNameList=PeriodNameList.split(",");
for(int j=0;j<SplitedPeriodNameList.length;j++){

               AgendaPeriodesBean=new AgendaPeriodesBean();

                 AgendaPeriodesBean.setAGENDA_PERIODE_TRANS_NAME(SplitedPeriodNameList[j].trim());
                 Agenda.AddAgendaPeriodTrans(AgendaPeriodesBean);
                  j++;    
               }
```

DAO Part.

```
    public Integer AddAgendaPeriodTrans(AgendaPeriodesBean Bean) throws        UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Integer updated = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();

    query.append("INSERT INTO AGENDA_PERIODE_TRANSLATION ( ");
    query.append("  AGENDA_PERIODE_TRANS_NAME ");
    query.append("  )  ");
    query.append("   VALUES (?)");
    int counter = 1;
    try {
        preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(new String(query));
        String str = new   String(Bean.getAGENDA_PERIODE_TRANS_NAME().getBytes("8859_1"), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("str : str : "+str);
        if (Bean.getAGENDA_PERIODE_TRANS_NAME()!= null) {
            preparedStatement.setString(counter++, Bean.getAGENDA_PERIODE_TRANS_NAME());
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setNull(counter++, Types.NVARCHAR);
        }



       updated = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
       System.out.println("AddAgendaPeriodTrans : "+sqlException.getMessage());
       updated=null;
    } finally {
        query = null;
        try {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close(); 
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }


    return updated ;

}
```